# Simulate user click in system activities with Android Espresso framework

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-testing, android-espresso

In my application I'm turning on `BlueTooth` when first `Activity` starts up.
It results in the system dialog asking for the authorization to activate the `BlueTooth`.

How can I asset that this dialog is present and click on the "Yes" Button with `Espresso` ? Is it possible ?

I tried the following but the view is not found in the layout hierarchy.

```
onView(withText("Bluetooth")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I guess this is because it's a system `Activity`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator) for this purpose. It is possible to combine Espresso tests with UIAutomator in one test case. The only limitation is that it requires API level 18+ which can be achieved by adding flavor in your `build.gradle` file.